# How to change font size using CSS variables and localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, css-variables

I'm trying to write a script in Javascript that will change the property of a CSS variable that determines the body's font size, based on a button click, that will then save to localstorage. I've referenced answers given in [increase / decrease font size and store in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091633/increase-decrease-font-size-and-store-in-cookie) and [How to store CSS variables in the browser memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471715/how-to-store-css-variables-in-the-browser-memory) and wrote a script that seemed to work in my text editor, but when implemented returned `NaNpx` instead of the correct number. This is my first foray into Javascript, so I'm not sure what went wrong. Any insight would be appreciated.

The CSS:

```css
body { background-color: #888; font-size: var(--mfont); transition: font-size .25s ease-in-out; }
:root { --mfont: 20px; --xxlfont: calc(var(--mfont) + 3px); --xxsfont: calc(var(--mfont) - 3px); }
```

The HTML:

```html
<p>test</p>

<p style="font-size: var(--xxlfont)">xxl test</p>

<p style="font-size: var(--xxsfont)">xxs test</p>

<button class="fontbutton" type="button" value="-1" title="Decrease font size">A-</button>
<button class="fontbutton" type="button" value="1" title="Increase font size">A+</button>
```

The Javascript:

```js
const root = document.querySelector(":root");
const fontbutton = document.querySelectorAll(".fontbutton");

if(localStorage.getItem("--mFont") != null) {
    root.style.setProperty("--mfont", localStorage.getItem("--mFont"));
};

fontbutton.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    root.style.setProperty("--mfont", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("--mFont")) + parseInt(this.value) + "px");
    localStorage.setItem("--mFont", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("--mFont")) + parseInt(this.value) + "px");
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially there is no set value in the `localStorage`, so you're calling `parseInt(null)`, which results in `NaN`. You can use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) on the root element instead to get the actual current `--mfont` value.

```js
fontbutton.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const prevFont = getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--mfont');
    root.style.setProperty("--mfont", parseInt(prevFont) + parseInt(this.value) + "px");
    localStorage.setItem("--mFont", parseInt(prevFont) + parseInt(this.value) + "px");
}));
```

Comment: See the code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/opmex4qa/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue might be with the line:

```
 root.style.setProperty("--mfont", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("--mFont")) + parseInt(this.value) + "px");
```

This line is attempting to parse the stored font size value from localStorage as an integer, but the stored value includes the "px" suffix, so the parsing returns NaN (Not a Number).

To fix this, you can modify the line to extract only the numeric value from the stored string value by using the parseInt() function with a radix of 10, and then add the button value and the "px" suffix:

```
root.style.setProperty("--mfont", parseInt(localStorage.getItem("--mFont"), 10) + parseInt(this.value) + "px");
```

This should correctly calculate and set the new font size value with the correct unit.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you are trying to access the value of `--mFont` from localStorage before it is set. When your code first runs, the `localStorage.getItem("--mFont")` will return `null` because the item has not been set yet. When you try to add `null` to a number using `parseInt()`, it will return `NaN`.

**That's why you are seeing `NaNpx` instead of the correct number.**

To fix this issue, you need to set a default value for `--mFont`, if it is not already in localStorage. You can do this by using the logical OR (`||`) operator to provide a default value if `localStorage.getItem("--mFont")` returns null.